WinDBG Args to Child
I have seen several tutorials where they mention that the 'Args to Child' section can be used to read the parameters passed into the method being called.
In my case, I am looking at a deadlock situation and am trying to find threads that are holding and waiting on locks.
0:007> kb
 # RetAddr               : Args to Child                                                           : Call Site
00 00007ff8`d2cd3f30     : 00007fff`00000002 00007fff`99ebb8b8 000001e7`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0x14
01 00007fff`f96ba234     : 00000094`4237f5b8 00007fff`f96d4d94 00000000`00000130 000001e7`e31567e0 : KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xf0
02 (Inline Function)     : --------`-------- --------`-------- --------`-------- --------`-------- : coreclr!Thread::DoAppropriateAptStateWait+0x4a [D:\a\_work\1\s\src\coreclr\vm\threads.cpp @ 3333] 
03 00007fff`f96ba085     : 00007fff`00000001 00007fff`00000001 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000001 : coreclr!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker+0x170 [D:\a\_work\1\s\src\coreclr\vm\threads.cpp @ 3467] 
04 00007fff`f96b9fa0     : 00000000`00000000 00007fff`00000001 00007fff`f96b9ef0 00007fff`99ebb8b8 : coreclr!Thread::DoAppropriateWait+0x85 [D:\a\_work\1\s\src\coreclr\vm\threads.cpp @ 3182] 


The first parameter to WaitForMultipleObjectsEx is a count, and the second is a pointer to an array of handles.
But looking at the hex displayed, I am not sure how to read the count?
is 00007fff f96d4d94 the array of handles?
As a test, I mocked up a simple C# example where I had 3 tasks all waiting on the same mutex, but what I noticed in WinDBG when viewing the thread stacks was that 2 of them had the same value for args to child (first two params) but the third one had something different?
How should I be reading this data?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25869983/17034

@HansPassant so whats the best way to figure out which thread owns the lock that the above thread is waiting on? I've seen the !locks command, but for this case, it doesn't show anything other than 'scanned X number of critical sections'

On 64-bit processes, Args to Child only shows the args that have spilled onto the stack. The first 4 arguments are stored in registers and can be quite difficult to recover by hand. A Windbg extension called CMKD does a pretty good job of recovering arguments in 64bit processes. See this answer for more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537828/ntkewaitforsingleobject-without-args/26538968#26538968
